# Why do I get an error if I didn't enter value?

Tags: c#

My program lets you choose the product, number of items from a combobox and lets you write the price in a textbox and it will calculate the amount (number of items * price), the 30% discount and the price after discount.

If every box is filled it won't show error, but if I leave the number of items combobox and/or price empty I get this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

And it will highlight this line: `price = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double amount, price, dis, 
    itemnum = double.Parse(comboBox2.Text),
    disrate = 30.0, totalafterdis;
    price = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    amount = price * itemnum;
    dis = amount * (disrate / 100);
    totalafterdis = amount - dis;

    textBox2.Text = amount.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = dis.ToString();
    textBox4.Text = totalafterdis.ToString();
}
```

I am not really familiar with C#, so I'm not sure if it's a rookie mistake or not.

Comment: you can't parse empty string (""), use try parse

Comment: An empty string cannot be parsed as a double. You have to provide some numeric string value for `double.Parse` to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't insert anything then it presents an empty string, which cannot be converted to an integer so try this:

```
    double temp;
    if(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out temp)){
       price = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but what does the "out" do in this code?

Comment: @ItssMohammed [out (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)

Comment: `Out` signifies a reference parameter. Sometimes methods must return more than one value then we can reference a variable using `Out` keyword, for our case `double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out temp)` return a boolean value whether it is convertible to `double` or not and if convertible then `out` reference that converted value to `temp` variable. So it returning two value at the same time, one `boolean` and another `double` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you left the textBox1 empty, you would get this error. This exception is basically telling you that, the value you have entered, is not in a suitable format for parsing to type double.

Here is an example. You will not/can not be able to parse, for instance, the value "hello", to a type double.  Your program at the moment is trying to parse an empty/null value to a double, which is not valid.

You should make use of the `TryParse` function, as below:

```
double result = 0;
bool isValidDouble = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out result);
//logical code here to check value of result
```

This will not throw an exception if your value of your textBox1 is invalid for parsing.

Comment: If I added the bool, I won't be able to calculate the amount. I tried it but it gives me an error, because one is double and the other is bool.

Comment: @ItssMohammed the bool value will be positive if the parsing action was successful, then your parsed value, your double value, will be the set into the result variable. Let me know if this is unclear.